# Is there any way to specify clip length instead of using `out` parameter?

Tags: mlt, melt-framework

I can play a video with melt if I do the command:

`melt video.mp4 in=50 out=1000`

The `in` parameter lets me specify that I want the video to start at frame 50. The `out` parameter lets me specify that I want to video to stop playing at frame 1000. My question is: Is there any way I can do something like this instead:

`melt video.mp4 in=50 length=950`

It would be very useful in a case where I want to mix together a lot of clips that needs to have the same length. Is there any such parameter available?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the length property is used to override the length computed from FFmpeg. If you set it and the out point is already less than the length, it does not change the out point. Really, the only time it makes much sense to set the length are when you know FFmpeg was wrong or in the case of a still image you need to run a very long time because the [default length of a producer is 15000 frames](https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/master/src/framework/mlt_producer.c#L95). In your case, I suggest to set both length=950 and out=949. Otherwise, if there is a clip less than 950 and setting only out, you would get less than 950. MLT repeats the last frame of a clip to extend it beyond the actual duration.